# Stacking columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df that looks like

| L.1 | L.2 | G.1 | G.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 9 | 13 |
| 2 | 6 | 10 | 14 |
| 3 | 7 | 11 | 15 |
| 4 | 8 | 12 | 16 |

This is just an arbitrary example but the structure of my df is the exactly the same. 4 column titles and then numbers under them. I would like to stack my columns in a way that it will look like

| L | G |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 11 |
| 4 | 12 |
| 5 | 13 |
| 6 | 14 |
| 7 | 15 |
| 8 | 16 |

If someone could help me in solving this, it would be great as I am having a really hard time doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) with remove `MultiIndex` in [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['L','G'], i='index', j='tmp', sep='.')
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
   L   G
0  1   9
1  2  10
2  3  11
3  4  12
4  5  13
5  6  14
6  7  15
7  8  16
```

Or split columns by [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and sorting `MultiIndex` by [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html), last also remove `MultiIndex`:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('.', expand=True)
df = df.stack().sort_index(level=[1,0]).reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
    G  L
0   9  1
1  10  2
2  11  3
3  12  4
4  13  5
5  14  6
6  15  7
7  16  8
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make each column to list and concatenate them and create a new dataframe based on the new list:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'L.1': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'L.2': [5, 6, 7, 8], 'G.1':[9, 10, 11, 12], 'G.2': [13, 14, 15, 16]})

new_df = pd.DataFrame({'L':df['L.1'].tolist()+df['L.2'].tolist(), 
'G':df['G.1'].tolist()+df['G.2'].tolist()})
```

Printing `new_df` will give you:

```
   L   G
0  1   9
1  2  10
2  3  11
3  4  12
4  5  13
5  6  14
6  7  15
7  8  16
```

Answer (score 1):

The columns have a pattern, some start with `L`, others start with `G`. We can use  [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html) to abstract the process; simply pass a list of new column names, and pass a regular expression to match the patterns:

```
df.pivot_longer(index = None,
                names_to = ['L', 'G'], 
                names_pattern = ['^L', '^G'])

   L   G
0  1   9
1  2  10
2  3  11
3  4  12
4  5  13
5  6  14
6  7  15
7  8  16
```

Using [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer), you can use the `.value` approach, along with a regular expression that contains groups - the grouped part is retained as a column header:

```
df.pivot_longer(index = None, 
                names_to = ".value", 
                names_pattern = r"(.).")

   L   G
0  1   9
1  2  10
2  3  11
3  4  12
4  5  13
5  6  14
6  7  15
7  8  16
```